# Particle Settings Link/Transfer

Tags: particles, linked-data, append

I'm just wondering, is there a way to transfer Particle System Settings from one .blend file to another? Something related to how appending and/or linking works.

For example, I have  x.blend which contains carpet particle settings and I want these settings to be transferred to 'y.blend', which currently doesn't contain any at all.

I'd love to hear your ideas.

Answer (score 7):

[`ParticleSettings`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.types.ParticleSettings.html) data is not readily accessible in append/link browser.

The easiest way I found to reuse it in another file, is to append or link the *mesh object* using it. Once the object is in the scene, you'll find every `ParticleSettings` data used by the object available to every other objects in the new file.

Comment: Except that you won't be able to edit its settings. If you meant to use it "as is" then it's perfect. Otherwise I don't see a way to gain access to such settings :(